# CakePHP: Send all variables to an element from within another element

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Imagine I have a very complex app. I have a controller that calls `characters.ctp`. Lots of DB work is done here for all the "characters".

Within `characters.ctp`, I call the `monsters` element. It prints out a monster and gives me the relevant info for the monsters, retrieved from the DB. Now within the `monsters` element, I want to make another element for `invertebrates` because they're so complex that they require lots of new view elements and CSS.

`invertebrates` does not carry the scope of `monster`'s variables it inherited through `$this->set()` from the controller. How can I send all variables to the child-element of an element? I'm using cake 2.8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using the `set()` method inside your element

With all the DB work done in the `characters` controller, you should do some controller job inside `monster` by re-setting the variables carried by `monster` using [View::set](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-View.html#_set) :

```
# /app/View/Elements/monster.ctp

//if you want to set variables one by one
$this->set('varForInvertebrates', $varForMonster);

//if you want to set an array of variables
$this->set(array(
    'var1' => $var1,
    'var2' => $var2,
    ...
));
```

---

## And if you still need data from a controller

If you have to compute data available in `monster` in order to use it in `invertebrates`, you can use [CakeObject::requestAction](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-CakeObject.html#_requestAction) to explicitly call a controller :

```
# /app/View/Elements/monster.ctp

// if the controller returns a variable
$this->set('varForInvertebrates', $this->requestAction('controller/method/param1/param2'));

// if the controller returns an array of variables
$this->set($this->requestAction('controller/method/param1/param2'));
```

Comment: Thanks! So, I did want to avoid manually sending over the variables, but I have most of them in a few arrays so it wasn't much trouble/clutter at all. I'm going to hold out on accepting the answer for a few days and if nothing comes up, I'll accept and press on.

Comment: @VaelVictus No problem! I've been working the past three weeks with CakePHP 2 and this is the only solution I've come to. It breaks a bit the MVC design pattern, but at least, it works! :)

Comment: @VaelVictus did you find a better solution to your problem?